# How to use Topshelf.Logging properly

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, topshelf

Any clue how to use `Topshelf.Logging` properly?

Do I have to pass `NLogLogWriter` to the constructor of  the service class?

And how to enable output to console as well?

```
class Program
    {
        #region Properties
        Topshelf.Logging.NLogLogWriter logger;
        static string mainLoggerName = "MainLogger";
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var  nlogLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            Topshelf.Logging.NLogLogWriter logger = new Topshelf.Logging.NLogLogWriter(nlogLogger, mainLoggerName);


            HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 
            {
                x.Service<ExSPCAgentService>(s =>                         
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new MyAgentService());      

                    // s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());               
                    s.WhenStarted(tc =>
                    {
                        // Add more config options if you need
                        tc.Start();
                    });
                    s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());                
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();                             
                x.UseNLog();
                x.SetDescription("MyAgentService");         
                x.SetDisplayName("MyAgentService");                        
                x.SetServiceName("MyAgentService");                        

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specify your logger, use the [overload of UseNLog](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/develop/src/Topshelf.NLog/NLogConfiguratorExtensions.cs#L38) that lets you specify a [LogFactory](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging).

For logging to console you would enable a [console target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target).

Edit: [docs](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/logging.html#nlog-integration)

> NLog Integration
>
> To enable logging via NLog, the Topshelf.NLog NuGet package is available. Once added to your project, configure Topshelf to use NLog via the configuration:

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.UseNLog();
});
```

> This will change the HostLogger to use NLog. An existing LogFactory can be passed as well, using an overload of the same method.

Comment: Thank you! The second part about the console target was useful. Would u mind to provide an example about LogFactory, please.

Comment: When using x.UseNLog(existingLogFactory), it isn't possible to reach this factory in another class. I tried to use LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(), but the LogManagers configuration is null. What must be done to can use the exist logFactory in other classes and modules? Btw, I use Lamar as IoC. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, you could make the log factory a static class member?